# Parallel line through a point

Tags: javascript, geometry

I have a line segment defined by two points, `P1` and `P2`, and a point `NP`. I want to create a parallel line passing through `NP`. I'm working in JavaScript and looking for a function to calculate the coordinates of the points `A` and `B` on the parallel line. Can someone provide a JavaScript function for this task, or suggest improvements to my existing code?

[image]

```
function createParallelLine(P1, P2, NP) {
  // Calculate the direction vector of the original line segment
  const directionVector = {
    x: P2.x - P1.x,
    y: P2.y - P1.y
  };

  // Normalize the direction vector
  const length = Math.sqrt(directionVector.x ** 2 + directionVector.y ** 2);
  const normalizedDirection = {
    x: directionVector.x / length,
    y: directionVector.y / length
  };

  // Calculate the perpendicular vector
  const perpendicularVector = {
    x: -normalizedDirection.y,
    y: normalizedDirection.x
  };

  // Calculate the new points A and B for the parallel line
  const A = {
    x: NP.x + perpendicularVector.x,
    y: NP.y + perpendicularVector.y
  };

  const B = {
    x: NP.x - perpendicularVector.x,
    y: NP.y - perpendicularVector.y
  };

  return { A, B };
}

// Example usage:
const P1 = { x: 1, y: 1 };
const P2 = { x: 4, y: 4 };
const NP = { x: 2, y: 2 };
const { A, B } = createParallelLine(P1, P2, NP);
console.log("Point A:", A);
console.log("Point B:", B);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We're not a code writing service, and all you've done is given a statement of intent, therefore implying we should do it for you. Do some research, give it a go, and if you're still struggling come back with a [mcve] of your code

Comment: Hint: If you knew the slope of the line, how could that help you with your problem ?

Comment: Since I cannot answer, I'll write it here. In the case where you don't need `A` and `B` to be as close as possible to `P1` and `P2`, simply use `A=NP`, and `B=P2+(NP-P1)`. It's parallel to `P1,P2`, and it goes through `NP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find projection of **NP** point onto **P1P2** line.

[image]

At first get vectors

```
Dir = (P2.X-P1.X, P2.Y-P1.Y)
W =   (NP.X-P1.X, NP.Y-P1.Y)
```

Point of projection of **NP** onto **P1P2** using scalar(dot) prodict is:

```
PP = P1 + Dir * (Dir.dot.W) / (Dir.dot.Dir)
```

and projection vector

```
V = NP - PP
```

Now ends of parallel segment are

```
P1' = P1 + V
P2' = P2 + V
```

Comment: Nice picture - how do you do it?

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski Using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org) application

Answer (score 1):

Lets `P1=[p1x,p1y]`, `P2=[p2x,p2y]`, `NP=[nx,ny]` then

```
W = [wx,wy] = (P2-P1)/2 = [(p2x-p1x)/2, (p2y-p1y)/2]
```

and

```
A = NP-W = [nx-wx, ny-wy]
B = NP+W = [nx+wx, ny+wy]
```

JS code

```js
function parallel([p1x,p1y],[p2x,p2y],[nx,ny]) {
  let wx = (p2x-p1x)/2;
  let wy = (p2y-p1y)/2;
  return [[nx-wx,ny-wy],[nx+wx,ny+wy]]
}


// TEST

let P1 = [2,3]; 
let P2 = [6,5];
let NP = [5,2];
let [A,B] = parallel(P1,P2,NP);

// print
console.log(`for P1=[${P1}], P2=[${P2}], NP=[${NP}] 
result is A=[${A}], B=[${B}]`);
```